# AngularJS + Django REST, как удалить объект из списка?

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить удаление объекта из списка?
В контроллере в js добавил функцию, которая выполняет 
`$http.delete('someurl' + id, {'id': id});`
Если я правильно понимаю, delete метод работает только для url вида `.../номер`, например, `/someurl/1`? Без номер в конце ругается, что такой метод `NOT ALLOWED`.

При использовании `$http.delete('someurl' + id, {'id': id});`
судя по консоли выполняется `DELETE http://someurl/1` и выдается ошибка `404 NOT FOUND`. Страницы `http://someurl/1` у меня нет и она мне как таковая не нужна, необходимо лишь каким-то образом удалить указанный объект. 
Добавление работает: `$http.put('someurl', {'id': id})`. Правда, в этом случае выдает ошибку `200 BAD REQUEST`, но объект добавляется.

В views.py:

```
class MyAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = MyModel

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method in ['PUT', 'POST']:
            return MySerializerBasic
        return MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(myfield=self.request.myfield).order_by('myorder')

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {'myfield': request.myfield.id, 'myorder': 100}
        data.update(request.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for myorder, element in enumerate(request.data['mylist']):
            self.model.objects.filter(
                myfield=request.myfield, id=element).update(
                myorder=myorder
            )
        print(request.data['mylist'])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Что и куда нужно добавить для удаления элемента?

Пытаюсь добавить

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = request.data['id']
        item = self.get_object(id)
        item.delete()
        print(request.data['id'])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Но ничего не происходит
В urls есть

```
url(r'^someurl$', MyApi.as_view())
```

**Обновление:**
Добавил в urls перед

```
url(r'^someurl$', MyApi.as_view())
```

строку

```
url(r'^someurl/(?P<pk>\d+)/', MyApi.as_view())
```

В контроллере для удаления вызываю

```
$http.delete('someurl/' + id + '/');
```

Выдает ошибку `404 NOT FOUND`

Функция удаления сейчас выглядит вот так:
 def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
            item = self.model.objects.get(pk=pk)
            item.delete()
            print(pk)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

Возникли дополнительные вопросы: почему ошибка 404, что за параметр pk - у меня нет такого поля в модели (делал по примеру https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445450/how-to-delete-an-object-using-django-rest-framework )
И как можно посмотреть вывод print(...)?

Comment: Обычным get запросом https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html

Comment: @korolariya небольшое уточнение, Django REST

Comment: По сути не важно какой фрэймвокр, в этом и суть rest  шлешь руками get  или курлом и должно удалять, потом делаешь так чтобы ангуляр делал то же самое, магии тут нет =)

Comment: @korolariya, rest не должен удалять по гету

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь так: в контроллере `$http.delete('someurl', {'id': id});`  в views.py: `def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        obj = self.get_object(pk)
        obj.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT` Выдает ошибку `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`. Pk - это primary key? Т.е. я должен передать первичный ключ объекта внутри angular? Но как получить из модели первичный ключ? Он же генерится автоматически. Я могу взять уникальные поля, у меня их два - id (то, что я сейчас передаю в запросе как id),и еще одно поле - user.

Comment: И вот это озадачивает; `mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView`, не нужно ли здесь куда-нибудь добавить Delete?

Comment: И как rest узнает, что ему нужно вызвать функцию delete(...) при запросе DELETE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всего-то нужно было добавить один параметр в url шаблон в urls.py.

Итого:

В urls.py нужно добавить шаблон для страницы удаления, в конце должен быть .../номер/, иначе запрос DELETE не будет выполняться.

```
url(r'^someurl/(?P<pk>\d+)/', MyApi.as_view(), name='delete')
```

где name='delete' - это имя функции

Т.е. урл будет вида

```
...someurl/123/
```

В views.py добавить

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
item = self.model.objects.get(pk=pk) 
item.delete() 
print(pk) 
return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
```

В контроллере вызываю

```
$http.delete('someurl/' + id + '/');
```

При таком запросе удалится объект с номером = id

Всем спасибо за помощь!